# Delete a key/value pair from an unordered_map C++

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, dictionary

I have two questions. First I have an `std::unordered_map<int,Object*>` where Object looks like this:

```
// Object.hpp
class Object {
    public:
        Object();
        ~Object(){};
        int   Id();
        void setId(int i);
    private:
        int id;
};
```

This `unordered_map` is put in a class called `DataSet` which is used as a container to hold all of these objects. In `DataSet` I want to be able to properly erase a key/value pair given an integer `id` from Object.

To do this I tried to create an iterator that finds the key by id, and then deletes the pointer to the iterator, and finally erases the key/value pair. It looks like this:

```
int DataSet::deleteObject(int id)
{
    std::unordered_map<int,Object*>::iterator found_it = objects.find(id);
    if(found_it != objects.end()) {
        delete *found_it;
        objects.erase(found_it);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

However, when I compile it I get this error:

```
dataset.cpp:44:9: error: cannot delete expression of type 'value_type'
      (aka 'pair<key_type, mapped_type>')
        delete *found_it;
```

Is there a correct way to erase the `Object` at that location?

Second, when writing a `clear()` method, I realize I can't just do `objects.clear()`, so I was wondering if there was a way to actually clear the `unordered_map`.

For example when I used a `std::vector` I was able to do this:

```
std::vector<Object *>::reverse_iterator object;
for(object = objects.rbegin(); object < objects.rend(); object++)
    delete(*object);
objects.clear();
```

But that won't work now for an `unordered_map`, so what is the right way to do this? The requirements that I am under make it so I can't change `Object`, or how the `unordered_map` is set up.

Comment: Is there a problem with [std::unordered_map::erase](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/erase)?

Comment: @OllieFord As far as I know it would create a memory leak since I'm just erasing the element but not actually getting rid of the pointer?

Comment: Also, you don't need to roll your own [clear](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/clear) method either.. Check the reference before rolling your own - it's the whole point of using STL!

Comment: @OllieFord I should have read that more closely, thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

The first part of the question is quite simple: the iterator reference the value and a given location which is of type `std::pair<int const, Object*>`. You can't `delete` such an object. You'll get the pointer using the `second` part of the object, e.g.:

```
delete found_it->second;
```

However, it is actually quite uncommon and error-prone to take care of this kind of maintenance. You are much better off not storing an `Object*` but rather a `std::unique_ptr<Object>`: the `std::unique_ptr<Object>` will automatically release the object upon destruction. That would also simplify removing an element:

```
int DataSet::deletObject(int id) {
    return objects.erase(id);
}
```

When storing `std::unique_ptr<Object>` you'll probably need to be a bit more verbose when inserting elements into the container, though, e.g.:

```
objects.insert(std::make_pair(key, std::unique_ptr<Object>(ptr)));
```

Given that your `Object` class doesn't have any virtual functions you could probably just store an `Object` directly, though:

```
std::unordered_map<int, Object> objects;
```

Comment: I tried to implement the `unordered_map` originally by declaring it as `std::unordered_map<int,std::unique_ptr<Object>>;` but I kept getting this error:       `no matching constructor for initialization of 'value_type'
      (aka 'pair<const key_type, mapped_type>')
        : __cc(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...) {}`

Comment: How did you try to add the elements? You'd use something like this: `object.insert(std::make_pair(key, std::unique_ptr<Object>(ptr)))`

Comment: oo that would be why, I was adding them incorrectly. As a side note, if I were to have `Object` become a virtual class with other classes inheriting from it, would I still want to use a `std::unique_ptr`?

Comment: If you don't have derived classes, you almost certainly wouldn't want to use pointers. If you got a base class, you can use `std::unique_ptr<Base>` to pointer to derived objects assuming `Base` has a `virtual` destructor.

Answer (score 2):

Dereferencing an `unordered_map::iterator` produces a `unordered_map::value_type&`, i.e. `pair<const Key, Value>&`.

You want

```
delete found_it->second;
objects.erase(found_it);
```

---

Stepping back a bit, are you sure you even need `std::unordered_map<int,Object*>` instead of `std::unordered_map<int,Object>`? If you use the latter you wouldn't have to worry about `delete`ing anything.

If you do need the `mapped_type` be an `Object*` you should use `std::unordered_map<int,std::unique_ptr<Object>>`. Again, this makes it unnecessary to manually `delete` the values before erasing an entry from the map.

Also, if `Object` is the base class for whatever types you're going to be adding to the map, don't forget that it needs a `virtual` destructor.

Comment: Since this is a test implementation of something larger I wouldn't need it here. But in reality, `Object` is an abstract class for a ton of different types of `Objects`.